# Including view specific assets in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, ejs, sails.js

I have my base layout which comes with the base scripts and css files but I also want to include view specific scripts. Otherwise I would have to include all scripts and use them in all views. Is this possible with Sails and EJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place  and  tags directly in your specific views:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
<h1>My Title</h1>
```

Where custom.css is in: `/assets/linker/styles/custom.css.

Comment: So EJS is automatically moving the styles and scripts to their appropriate header and footer places in the base layout? I think what I'm looking for is template inheritance / blocks.

Comment: The gruntfile.js is automatically moving the styles and scripts to their appropriate header and footer places in `layout.ejs`. I'm not familiar with template inheritance/blocks, what are they?

Comment: Cool. I didn't know that. Well with template inheritance you can simply define blocks in your layout and override them from your view. This way you can define a `view_scripts` block in the layout and override it with your view specific scripts from out the view.

Comment: Excuse me, but if I put a <link> to the css I need, it will be placed exactly at the place I put it, and it will occur between the body tags. What am I doing wrong, or has behavior changed since Dec 26th 2013?